# How to get auto-imports with Kotlin in VSCode

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get VSCode to auto-create import lines in Kotlin?

e.g.

1. User enters `val thread = Thread()` in Kotlin source in VSCode
2. User invokes auto-importer via hotkey or whatever
3. VSCode automatically inserts `import java.lang.Thread` at the top

The Java extension has a command to do exactly this (with alt+shift+o).

Surely there must be a Kotlin extension or command for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: We have since come to the conclusion that VSCode is not jot ready for Kotlin yet, unfortunately.  My team switched to IntelliJ IDEA.